# get the value of all the checked checkboxes on button click

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, repeater

I have created a table in my `.aspx` file that looks like this:

[image]

Here is the code that does this:

```
<!-- code for generating the "add selected sessions" button -->
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><strong>Individual Sessions</strong></td>
        <td >
            <div class="addButton" style="text-align: center;">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" Text="Add Selected Sessions" OnClick="btnAddToCart_Click" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<!-- add all the sessions for the user to select -->
<asp:Repeater ID="rptFeesSession" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table >
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnIsSession" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("isSession")%>' />
        <tr runat="server" visible='<%# Eval("isSession")%>'>
            <td valign="top" colspan="2" style="position: relative;">
                <asp:HyperLink CssClass="siteColorFG popBtn" ID="hlFeeType" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("title")%>' NavigateUrl="javascript:;"/>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <div class="">
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="LinkButton3" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("id")%>'CssClass="checkB" OnClick="btnAddToCart_Click" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("amount", "{0:C}")%>' />
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

In my code behind file i want to capture all the checkboxes that have been checked and their respective `CommandArgument` values.

```
protected void btnAddToCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{
    using (MyEntities db = new MyEntities())
    {
        //button was clicked. fetch all the check boxes from the rptFeesSession repeater into an int[]


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code (including conceptual / logic)

1. Item events in a `Repeater` should address item related things.
2. `Click` event handler has no access to `CommandArgument` attribute. Use `Command` instead.
3. `Checkbox` control doesn't support `onclick` event.
4. `Checkbox` events can run immediately only when there is `AutoPostback="true"`.

If you want to refresh all repeater data on change of any checkbox then you can do something like this.

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="scriptMgr" /><%-- Strongly recommended --%>
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptFeesSession" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnIsSession" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("isSession")%>' />
                <tr runat="server" visible='<%# Eval("isSession")%>'>
                    <td colspan="2" style="position: relative;">
                        <asp:HyperLink CssClass="siteColorFG popBtn" ID="hlFeeType" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("title")%>' NavigateUrl="javascript:;" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div class="">
                            <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidID" Value='<%#Eval("id") %>' />
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="LinkButton3"
                                AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="checkB"
                                OnCheckedChanged="LinkButton3_CheckedChanged" runat="server"
                                Text='<%#Eval("amount", "{0:C}")%>' />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>


//.cs
protected void LinkButton3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal total = 0;
    using (MyEntities db = new MyEntities())
    {
        foreach (RepeaterItem item in rptFeesSession.Items)
        {
            var chk = item.FindControl("LinkButton3") as CheckBox;
            if(chk!=null && chk.Checked){
                string id = (item.FindControl("hidID") as HiddenField).Value;
                total += decimal.Parse(chk.Text);
                //do stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks. This is useful. I will make those edits. But what i really want is that on the click on the button i want to find out all the check boxes that are checked. I dont want to do anything when items are checked.

Comment: OK. If you don't want to update immediately then don't include `autopostback="true"`and the code will run on `addButton_Click`.

Comment: Why did you add these three lines `<asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="scriptMgr" /><%-- Strongly recommended --%><asp:UpdatePanel runat="server"><ContentTemplate>`?

Comment: how will the above code grab all the checkboxes when the "Add selected sessions" is clicked? I dont see how you show that on Button click something will occur. You have provided code only for checkbox clicks.

Comment: 1. `ScriptManager` and `UpdatePanel` are optional / recommended to avoid full post back. 2. **Add Selected Sessions** wasn't include in OP and my answer. Its `click` event will fire `OnCheckedChanged` events of all checkboxes if they were not fired by `autopostback="true"`

Comment: this line was always in the OP `<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" Text="Add Selected Sessions" OnClick="btnAddToCart_Click" />
`

Comment: Run my code inside your `btnAddToCart_Click` handler. No `autopostback`. `CommandArgument` is only available in `onCommand` handler.

Comment: and remove `btnAddToCart_Click` from `checkbox` control.